# Bitlocker recovery key

Tags: windows-10

My windows 10 lenovo laptop is asking for my bitlocker keyw,hich I don't remember. This is due to automatic repairs.How can I erase and format the drive to remove the bitlocker since I don't need the data?

Comment: You should be able to boot to the installation environment of your choice and delete the partitions on the drive.  You would need the recovery key in order to solve this problem any other way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format drive correctly for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1506615/format-drive-correctly-for-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily boot from an OS installed on a usb to simply delete the partitions and format the hdd. You can use windows installation media or rufus to create such drive.